# Is what I wrote an actual monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

I have been trying to understand monads and since I recently understood what zippers are I thought I might try to combine both ideas. (>>=) does what I think monads should do, namely it lets me combine movements around the zipper in the form of `moveRight >>= moveLeft >>= goAhead >>= return` but I feel like I'm missing something because, among other things, I can't seem to fit its type to what a monad should be, namely `Ma -> (a -> Mb) -> Mb`. Any help would be welcome.

```
module MonadZipper where

import Prelude hiding (return, (>>=))

data Node a = Fork a (Node a) (Node a)
            | Passage a (Node a)
            | DeadEnd a
              deriving (Show)

data Branch a = TurnLeft a (Node a)
              | TurnRight a (Node a)
              | StraightAhead a
                deriving (Show)

type Trace a = [Branch a]
type Zipper a = (Trace a, Node a)


type Movement a = Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
--not sure whether this wrapping makes sense

turnLeft :: Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
turnLeft (t, (Fork v l r)) = Just (TurnLeft v r:t, l)
turnLeft _                 = Nothing

turnRight :: Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
turnRight (t, (Fork v l r)) = Just (TurnRight v l:t, r)
turnRight _                 = Nothing

goAhead :: Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
goAhead (t, Passage v a) = Just (StraightAhead v:t, a)
goAhead _                = Nothing

(>>=) :: Movement a -> Movement a -> Movement a
(>>=) turner func = \zippo ->
                      case turner zippo of
                        Nothing -> Nothing
                        Just tree -> func tree

return :: Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
return tree = Just tree
```

Comment: Your `return` suggests that the monad is `Maybe`, and this does not match with the `(>>=)` which should have type `(a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b`.

Comment: Your `>>=` should be named `>>`, at best. For a propoer monad you need to have `(>>=) :: Movement a -> (a -> Movement b) -> Movement b`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `Movement` type is a lot like a combination of the `Maybe` monad (to allow for failed movements) plus the `State` monad with the current `Zipper a` as the state:

```
State (Zipper a) b  =  Zipper a -> (b, Zipper a)
```

I'm cheating with the `=` here .  This isn't the precise definition of the `State` type, but these types are isomorphic, so you can think of `State` as being equal to this type.

In other words, you've come close to reinventing the transformer-based monad:

```
type Movement' a b = StateT (Zipper a) Maybe b
```

The main difference is that `Movement' a b` is isomorphic to:

```
Zipper a -> Maybe (b, Zipper a)
```

so it's got that extra `b` value that you haven't included.

Sooo....

If you were to rewrite your `Movement` type as:

```
type Movement a b = Zipper a -> Maybe (b, Zipper a)
```

you'd be on to something.  Here, `Movement` isn't a monad -- instead, `Movement a` is a monad which can be applied to an underlying type `Movement a b`.

If you're familiar with `Either` as a monad, it's the same thing:  `Either` by itself isn't a monad, but `Either String` is a monad that can be applied to another type like `Either String Double` to represent, say, a computation that returns either a `Double` result or a `String` error message.

Similarly, your `Movement a` is a monad that can be applied to another type `Movement a b` to represent a computation that returns a `b` while maintaining a `Zipper a` as an internal state and allowing failure by returning `Nothing`.

Moving on, your `turnLeft`, `turnRight`, and `goAhead` are pure effects:  they modify the state (the `State` part of the monad), signalling error if an impossible move is made (the `Maybe` part of the monad), but they don't need to return anything.  That's okay, because they can return `()`.  Here's how `goAhead` would work:

```
goAhead :: Movement a ()
-- same as:  goAhead :: Zipper a -> Maybe ((), Zipper a)
goAhead (t, Passage v a) = Just ((), (StraightAhead v:t, a))
goAhead _                = Nothing
```

and you can make analogous changes to `turnLeft` and `turnRight`.

Now, redefining `return` is relatively easy.  It should pack an arbitrary value of type `b` into your `Movement a` monad without having any "effects".  See if you can fill in the blank:

```
return :: b -> Movement a b
-- same as:  return :: b -> Zipper a -> Maybe (b, Zipper a)
-- in definitino below, right hand side should be:
--     Movement a b = Zipper a -> Maybe (b, Zipper a)
return b = \z -> _
```

Of course, `(>>=)` is a little harder.  See if you can figure it out:

```
(>>=) :: Movement a b -> (b -> Movement a c) -> Movement a c
-- in definition below, right-hand side is a:
--   Movement a c = Zipper a -> Maybe (b, Zipper a)
mb >>= bToMc = \z1 -> case mb z1 of ...
```

If you give up, I've included the answers below.

With this monad, things can get a little more interesting.  For example, you can can introduce an action that *does* return something.  How about the set of valid moves?

```
data Move = LeftOk | RightOk | StraightOk

validMoves :: Movement a [Move]
validMoves z@(t, n) = case n of
  (Fork _ _ _)  -> Just ([LeftOk, RightOk], z)
  (Passage _ _) -> Just ([StraightOk], z)
  (DeadEnd _)   -> Just ([], z)
```

or the element at the current position:

```
peek :: Movement a a
peek z@(_, n) = case n of
  Fork a _ _  -> Just (a, z)
  Passage a _ -> Just (a, z)
  DeadEnd a   -> Just (a, z)
```

Using this, you can construct a monadic action that walks the zipper, always using the first valid move, and returns the value at the dead end:

```
findDeadEnd :: Movement a a
findDeadEnd =
    validMoves >>= \moves ->
    case moves of [] -> peek
                  (mv:_) -> (case mv of StraightOk -> goAhead
                                        LeftOk     -> turnLeft
                                        RightOk    -> turnRight)
                            >>= \() -> findDeadEnd
```

If this was a real monad instance, you could write the above more cleanly in `do` notation.

Not bad, huh?

Anyway, the full code with the answers for `return` and `>>=` is below.  Next, you might want to try wrapping your `Movement` into a newtype so you can define instances:

```
newtype Movement a b 
  = Movement { runMovement :: Zipper a -> Maybe (b, Zipper a) }
instance Functor (Movement a) where
instance Applicative (Movement a) where
instance Monad (Movement a) where
```

and see if you can rewrite everything to make it a real `Monad`.

The full example:

```
module MonadZipper where

import Prelude hiding (return, (>>=))

data Node a = Fork a (Node a) (Node a)
            | Passage a (Node a)
            | DeadEnd a
              deriving (Show)

data Branch a = TurnLeft a (Node a)
              | TurnRight a (Node a)
              | StraightAhead a
                deriving (Show)

type Trace a = [Branch a]
type Zipper a = (Trace a, Node a)

type Movement a b = Zipper a -> Maybe (b, Zipper a)

(>>=) :: Movement a b -> (b -> Movement a c) -> Movement a c
mb >>= bToMc = \z1 -> case mb z1 of
                        Nothing -> Nothing
                        Just (b, z2) -> bToMc b z2

return :: b -> Movement a b
return b z = Just (b, z)

turnLeft :: Movement a ()
turnLeft (t, (Fork v l r)) = Just ((), (TurnLeft v r:t, l))
turnLeft _                 = Nothing

turnRight :: Movement a ()
turnRight (t, (Fork v l r)) = Just ((), (TurnRight v l:t, r))
turnRight _                 = Nothing

goAhead :: Movement a ()
goAhead (t, Passage v a) = Just ((), (StraightAhead v:t, a))
goAhead _                = Nothing

data Move = LeftOk | RightOk | StraightOk

validMoves :: Movement a [Move]
validMoves z@(t, n) = case n of
  (Fork _ _ _)  -> Just ([LeftOk, RightOk], z)
  (Passage _ _) -> Just ([StraightOk], z)
  (DeadEnd _)   -> Just ([], z)

peek :: Movement a a
peek z@(_, n) = case n of
  Fork a _ _  -> Just (a, z)
  Passage a _ -> Just (a, z)
  DeadEnd a   -> Just (a, z)

findDeadEnd :: Movement a a
findDeadEnd =
    validMoves >>= \moves ->
    case moves of [] -> peek
                  (mv:_) -> (case mv of StraightOk -> goAhead
                                        LeftOk     -> turnLeft
                                        RightOk    -> turnRight)
                            >>= \() -> findDeadEnd

test = case findDeadEnd ([], (Fork 1 (Fork 2 (Passage 3 (DeadEnd 4))
                                             (DeadEnd 5))
                                     (Passage 6 (DeadEnd 7)))) of
         Just (v, _) -> print v
```